# What is 'Activator' as mentioned in this blog?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm new to Scala and I don't have a grasp of all the tools yet. Can someone please tell me what 'Activator' this blog post is referring to?

http://yeghishe.github.io/2016/10/16/writing-aws-lambdas-in-scala.html

Comment: https://www.lightbend.com/activator/download

Comment: There are search engines like "google" (alternatives - Bing, Yahoo, DuckDuckGo) in the world of internet. And SO is not one of them.

Comment: I used search engines, but I found more than one 'Activator' sh. Maybe I'm better at searching than you are. :)

Comment: I found the answer by clicking on the "activator" tag on the blog post you linked ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He is referring to Lightbend Activator and its specific syntax:
https://www.lightbend.com/activator/download

The same blog also has some more information about Activator:
http://yeghishe.github.io/2015/06/16/activator-and-my-activator-templates.html